# Is there more information on the spell Galder's Tower available from previous editions?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dungeons-and-dragons

I'm playing 5e, and planning my 3rd level spell acquisitions. I came across the spell [Galder's Tower](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/galders-tower). The spell description says:

> You conjure a two-story tower made of stone, wood, or similar suitably
>   sturdy materials.

It then goes on to describe a few more of the tower's details such as how rooms are furnished and what happens when you upcast the spell. I'm wondering if this is a *'new to 5e'* spell, and if it isn't

**Is there more information on the spell Galder's Tower available from previous editions?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, the spell *Galder's Tower* is new in 5th edition

The adventure module *Lost Laboratory of Kwalish* (published Nov 2018) introduces this new spell and two other references to the wizard Galder - the spell *Galder's Speedy Courier* and the magical item *Galder's Bubble Pipe*. All of these, and the character of Galder, were first published/referenced in this 5e module.

There's a bit of a tragic backstory to these, as their inclusion in this module was intended to immortalise the wizard Galder - the player character of a Redditor and D&D fan, [/u/SomeHairyGuy](https://www.reddit.com/user/SomeHairyGuy/) AKA Laurence Withey, who was dying of cancer. Sadly, he passed away at about the same time the module was actually published.

This [comicbook.com article](https://comicbook.com/gaming/2018/11/12/dungeons-and-dragons-lost-laboratory-of-kwalish-/) summarises the situation well. Essentially, SomeHairyGuy's wish to have his wizard immortalised in D&D lore was picked up by the fan community, causing Wizards to take notice and ultimately Mike Mearls got in touch to ask him to design a signature spell as Galder's legacy.

You can also see the thread on Reddit where Laurence posts [initial designs of the spells and item](https://www.reddit.com/r/AdventuresOfGalder/comments/9lut46/hello_everyone_its_me_i_still_have_an_unanswered/):

> Hello everyone, it's me. I still have an unanswered email from Mike Mearls about what kind of signature spell Galder can leave in his legacy.
>
> It's been harder than I expected to come up with a spell!
>
> [...]
>
> I'll take the time today if I can to edit this post with more, but to begin with, here's a couple ideas I had: [...]

Barring editing for style and clarity, the published *Galder's Tower* spell is mechanically almost identical to the version designed by Laurence here in October 2018.

*Lost Laboratory of Kwalish* itself includes a special acknowledgement for Laurence in its [acknowledgements section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/llok/acknowledgments-and-final-thanks):

> We would also like to extend special acknowledgment of a designer for certain spells and magic items appearing within this adventure. To Laurence Withey — we hope this presentation of your material does justice to Galder, and we humbly thank you for allowing us to include it.