# Galder's Tower Kinetic Weapon

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, falling

Assuming you could find a stable position in the air, like on a flying mount, a tall ladder, etc. Could you cast Galder's Tower, summoning a 2 plus story stone structure high up in the air. So that it would then plummet down on an unsuspecting enemy? If so, what damage dice would you even have the unfortunate victim roll.

The text of the spell in question
(Source: *Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*)

> 3rd-level conjuration
>
> **Casting Time**: 10 minutes
> **Range**: 30 feet
> **Components**: V, S, M (a fragment of stone, wood, or other building material)
> **Duration**: 24 hours
>
> You conjure a two-story tower made of stone, wood, or similar suitably sturdy materials. The tower can be round or square in shape. Each level of the tower is 10 feet tall and has an area of up to 100 square feet. Access between levels consists of a simple ladder and hatch. Each level takes one of the following forms, chosen by you when you cast the spell:
>
> - A bedroom with a bed, chairs, chest, and magical fireplace
> - A study with desks, books, bookshelves, parchments, ink, and ink pens
> - A dining space with a table, chairs, magical fireplace, containers, and cooking utensils
> - A lounge with couches, armchairs, side tables and footstools
> - A washroom with toilets, washtubs, a magical brazier, and sauna benches
> - An observatory with a telescope and maps of the night sky
> - An unfurnished, empty room
>
> The interior of the tower is warm and dry, regardless of conditions outside. Any equipment or furnishings conjured with the tower dissipate into smoke if removed from it. At the end of the spell’s duration, all creatures and objects within the tower that were not created by the spell appear safely outside on the ground, and all traces of the tower and its furnishings disappear.
>
> You can cast this spell again while it is active to maintain the tower’s existence for another 24 hours. You can create a permanent tower by casting this spell in the same location and with the same configuration every day for one year.
>
> ***At Higher Levels***. When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 4th level or higher, the tower can have one additional story for each slot level beyond 3rd.

Spell Lists: Wizard

Comment: Related: [Is there more information on the spell Galder's Tower available from previous editions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167177/23547)

Answer (score 4):

### The tower is meant to be cast on the ground

The spell [*Galder's Tower*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/galders-tower) says:

> At the end of the spell’s duration, all creatures and objects within the tower that were not created by the spell appear **safely outside on the ground**, and all traces of the tower and its furnishings disappear.

What ground? While this is a bit indirect, the reference to *the ground outside* must refer to the ground outside where the tower is standing, which means the tower must be standing on [the ground](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/82302/75095).

You cannot cast it into mid-air, whether you are on a flying mount or not, nor can  you cast it up 30 feet over the heads of some enemies.

If your DM thinks otherwise, they also must come up with damage for the resulting crash. The upper end benchmark for a third-level damage spell is *fireball*, with 8d6 damage, and a Dexterity save for half damage, which they should keep in mind for balance reasons. (Here the area is smaller, so maybe the damage could be a bit larger.)

It would be better if the spell directly said the ground on which the tower must be cast.

Keep in mind that *Lost Laboratory of Kwalish* is an "Extra Life" module created for a charity event, not a core rulebook or commercially produced splatbook or module. With that, it likely did not undergo the same editing process as those other materials, and it shows here. Instead of the normal team of 4-5 editors, a single person was responsible for finding errors and omissions (and for the layout, too).

Comment: Some commentary on the development of the spell [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AdventuresOfGalder/comments/9lut46/hello_everyone_its_me_i_still_have_an_unanswered/)

Comment: Related: [Is there more information on the spell Galder's Tower available from previous editions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167177/33569)

Comment: Isn't there a rule that conjurations need to appear on a surface that is capable of supporting them, to prevent exactly this scenario? No summoning blue whales on land, let alone way in the air above your enemies.

Comment: @nick012000 Some spells include language like that but I'm not aware of a general rule for this in 5e. Could it be that you remember that rule from a different edition or system?